# How to share build step in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

Qt Creator has an option to add custom build steps for the project which is cool. However the command line for the additional build step is stored in the .pro.user file which should not be added to version control, because it contains machine specific data. When I push my project to the repo and then clone it in another location the user file is different and the custom build steps are missing. How can I share my custom build steps so the project is built easily on every machine with Qt installed?

Comment: example.pro.shared - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19312995/492336

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the custom build steps with `QMAKE_POST_LINK` commands
([QMAKE_POST_LINK Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-post-link))

They can be linked to a script that can be committed:

```
win32 {
    QMAKE_POST_LINK = install/win/deploy
}
unix {
    QMAKE_POST_LINK = install/unix/deploy
}
```

To create pre-build steps, [this](http://colby.id.au/pre-pre-build-commands-with-qmake/) is a nice example: [Pre-pre-build commands with qmake](http://colby.id.au/pre-pre-build-commands-with-qmake/).

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get to my IDE. And how to make pre-build step?

Comment: `QMAKE_PRE_LINK` - Lol look at the link I posted, it was right after

Comment: Btw if you want to place a file instead of a command - that is what I did because it was too many commands - the file 'deploy" must be executable type

Comment: Isn't  QMAKE_PRE_LINK executed after build but before link ? I need to invoke script which generates code to be compiled among the other source files so it needs to be invoked before source building.

Comment: Updated answer with a link to an example that I think will be helpful to what you need.